# Как преобразовать строку в массив uint с основанием 2^32

Tags: c#

Подскажите пожалуйста как из например "12413523578274952895672975235" сделать массив uint[] digits в котором будут храниться коэффициенты разложения этого длинного числа с основанием 2^32.

Смотрел в исходниках библиотеки System.Numerics, но ничего понять не смог.
Подскажите алгоритм который парсит строку в массив uint[] digits, где digits[i] коэффициент разложения данного числа с основанием 2^32

Comment: у вас проблемы с [переводом числа](http://inf.e-alekseev.ru/text/Schisl_perevod.html) из десятичной системы в систему с основанием `2^32`?

Comment: нет у меня проблема в том что я не знаю как из строки получить массив такой. Не получиться же Int32.Parse("12413523578274952895672975235") и потом делить его на 2^32 чтобы перевести в систему с основанием 2^32.

Comment: у вас же в тегах есть BigInteger, `var bi = BigInteger.Parse("12413523578274952895672975235");` ?

Comment: _Подскажите алгоритм который парсит строку в массив uint[]_ - `str.Select(uint.Parse).ToArray()`

Comment: @Grundy можно вопрос а данный вами код сможет спарсить  "12413523578274952895672975235" в массив uint[] digits где digits[i] это коэффициент данного числа с основанием 2^32?

Comment: Нет, данный код получает массив с коэффициентами данного числа с основанием 10. Но это остается массивом `uint[]`

Comment: `Подскажите пожалуйста как из например "12413523578274952895672975235" сделать массив uint[] digits в котором будут храниться коэффициенты разложения этого длинного числа с основанием 2^32.`

Comment: Извиняюсь у вас вроде 60к репутации, и я не знал что даже для вас нужно делать будет такую правку, но мне не сложно)

Comment: `Подскажите алгоритм который парсит строку в массив uint[] digits где digits[i] коэффициент разложения данного числа с основанием 2^32` 1) парсите строку в массив коэффициентов с основанием 10 2) реализуете деление/сложение/вычитание - те операции, что вам нужны для таких чисел с основанием 10 3) Используете эти операции, чтобы получить массив коэффициентов с основанием 2^32

Comment: А что именно ты смотрел в исходниках библиотеки System.Numerics и не понял?

Comment: @Grundy ну вот по этой ссылке [ссылка](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Numerics/System/Numerics/BigNumber.cs)
В файле BigNumber.cs есть метод TryParseBigInteger и вот на этом моменте мне не понятно практически все.

Comment: Конкретно для твоей задачи в этой функции важна [NumberToBigInteger](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Numerics/System/Numerics/BigNumber.cs,0eee06380711a113) - и ее содержание очень простое

Comment: @Grundy да функция простая и я понял что и как она делает. Но возникла проблема при value *= 10; и я не понимаю как происходит умножение.
Если BigInteger это считай массив uint[] то как происходит умножение и в какой момент массив digits формируется в массив где digis[i] это коэффициент разложения. Если вы разбираетесь в этом не могли бы вы пожалуйста в виде ответа написать функцию которая принимает строку а выдает уже или класс BigInteger (упрощенный где только sign и сам массив) ну или выдает сам массив uint[] digits где digits[i] коэффициент разложения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подходов для преобразования может быть несколько: можно реализовать деление в столбик и стандартный алгоритм для перевода числа в систему с другим основанием, а можно воспользоваться подходом из `System.Numerics`, в котором преобразование можно свести к следующему алгоритму:

```
создаем пустой объект большого числа, эквивалентный 0.
проход по строке:
  умножаем число на 10
  добавляем к числу цифру из строки
```

Отсюда видно, что для реализации данного подхода необходимо реализовать как минимум два вспомогательных метода:

1. умножение на число
2. добавление числа.

---

Со сложением все просто: обычное сложение в столбик

1. добавляем число к младшему разряду
2. если полученное значение меньше основания закончить
3. иначе перенести лишнее в старший разряд

---

С умножением аналогично, умножаем каждый разряд на переданное число и переносим лишнее в старшие разряды.

---

Итоговый код класса может выглядеть так:

```
class BN
{
    private List<uint> coefs;
    private const long BASE = (long)uint.MaxValue + 1;

    public BN(uint init = 0)
    {
        coefs = new List<uint>() { init };
    }
    public void Add(uint val)
    {
        long carry = val;
        for (int i = 0; i < coefs.Count; i++)
        {
            var sum = coefs[i] + carry; // вычисляем сумму
            coefs[i] = (uint)(sum % BASE); // нормализуем значение
            carry = sum / BASE; // вычисляем лишнее для переноса в старший разряд
            if (carry == 0) // если переносить нечего, то и цикл продолжать не нужно
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (carry != 0) // если после выхода из цикла осталось лишнее, добавляем еще один разряд
        {
            coefs.Add((uint)carry);
        }
    }
    public void Mul(uint val)
    {
        var dVal = (decimal)val;
        var carry = 0m;
        for (int i = 0; i < coefs.Count; i++)
        {
            var mul = coefs[i] * dVal + carry; // вычисляем произведение и добавляем то, что пришло от младших разрядов
            coefs[i] = (uint)(mul % BASE); // нормализуем значение
            carry = Math.Floor(mul / BASE); // вычисляем лишнее для переноса в старший разряд
        }

        while(carry != 0) // если после выхода осталось лишнее
                          // добавляем необходимое количество разрядов
        {
            coefs.Add((uint)(carry % BASE)); 
            carry = Math.Floor(carry / BASE);
        }
    }

    public static BN Parse(string v)
    {
        var bn = new BN(0); // создаем 0
        foreach (var c in v) // бежим по строке
        {
            bn.Mul(10); // умножаем на 10
            bn.Add(uint.Parse(c.ToString())); // добавляем число из строки
        }
        return bn;
    }
}
```